# Typescript dynamic type based on the parent functions parameter enum value

Tags: typescript, types, enums, conditional-types

I am trying to conditionally define a child functions parameter type based on a enum variable obtained from the parent functions parameter value.

It seems that when a function parameter value is used to conditionally define a child functions parameter type, typescript is unable to understand the condition.

See example:

```js
enum PaymentMethodTypes {
  CARD = "card",
  DIRECT_DEBIT = "direct_debit",
}

type Card = {
  type: PaymentMethodTypes.CARD
}

type DirectDebit = {
  type: PaymentMethodTypes.DIRECT_DEBIT
}

const Component = ({ paymentType }: {paymentType: PaymentMethodTypes}) => { 
  type PaymentMethod = typeof paymentType extends PaymentMethodTypes.CARD ? Card : DirectDebit;

  const method = (paymentMethod: PaymentMethod) => {
    console.info(paymentMethod.type)
    if (paymentType === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD) {
      console.info(paymentMethod.type === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD);
      // ERROR: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'PaymentMethodTypes.DIRECT_DEBIT' and 'PaymentMethodTypes.CARD' have no overlap.
    }
  }
}
```

---

When a variable is defined, rather than via the function parameter or a conditional value, Typescript is able to understand the type condition correctly.

See example:

```js
enum PaymentMethodTypes {
  CARD = "card",
  DIRECT_DEBIT = "direct_debit",
}

type Card = {
  type: PaymentMethodTypes.CARD
}

type DirectDebit = {
  type: PaymentMethodTypes.DIRECT_DEBIT
}

const paymentType = PaymentMethodTypes.Card;

const Component = () => { 
  type PaymentMethod = typeof paymentType extends PaymentMethodTypes.CARD ? Card : DirectDebit;

  const method = (paymentMethod: PaymentMethod) => {
    console.info(paymentMethod.type)
    if (paymentType === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD) {
      console.info(paymentMethod.type === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD);
      // This now works
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general, TypeScript can't narrow the type of X (`paymentMethod`) based on a guard on Y (`paymentType`). Why are you using `paymentType` rather than `paymentMethod.type` in the `if`? Perhaps more context would help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) parameter to obtain the narrowed type of `paymentType`.

[See TS Playground for why this is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgTwqALgWWCgFgewCYAqCADsAM5QDeAUFFAMICCASgCJQC8UARAMZwAnPNwA0tKKwCSzAKL0CAfVYyAQpIKceeAJYDgvFArzAARtpSjqAX2rUUJYA0F5NNOvdIAuWImQh0mLiEDmQAdExs1rYejqy6+iispuau4jHe8EioGNj4RKRhUrLySqrqUdS8OCBkKAw4EMTVqJoAFJRQxL6o+Y5W3pRdWf69Gd3+OUG9ZFYAlJwAfFRQaQ5QKOQoAIyaMTgAZp3jKL3iAPRndAB6APyrpOubAEyamX4BucEFUMAAHhsgPAUN7ZQJ5ELhFjsG5OIRQbxxPQGJJmFDnS5QW73RwgiZglxcPaHIbvXo-f6gIE+YYfKYQiLQ2EuBHxZHJFAAbnR1zu7jWG1qAGZXsdJuCCpC2FAAD7U95ir7kUJFOSKZRqDR-AFU3G08VKhlQGH0ZzwiSsxLsrl0C482x0Ko1OrIT5tEmgz5jGkK+YcJZuOhQR1kHAAG2AoW0IH2OFa7rxn1CMVm4jo2kOceOZI4OblHrpEoZ8wDgaD1RD4cj0dj8b1eCTaxzXF1CumktYs2tpagtpkzGYAHlmN4CFhtBRHToUNpqlAAO7aUOhqBwUNzxAUPQoMACEBQADk+1XZGA+6gZCjvEc2GvIQPLfxbZVJXV6jPcEB99Fj-pULPWDgAA3RwQBwKAcGAgRQzgYhQlTKAbDoGwbEqcs6noBomhAVAADFtF+TQAB5NQpQFgW-T5pgWdojhpMl+ioWtRigAg5kWZZsTzBMgk0EjtXI70f0LKEjSZM1EQSFFzC7W1MTucRg2dfE3QooIvXlfFfX9eDgzDCMoxjTNBMTZN4PTKAjNJRtcwfSjfzYYt4Idcs9KrQzawVBsHibLi6zbIsuyQ8RkKAA)

```js
const ComponentFix = <T extends PaymentMethodTypes>({ paymentType }: {paymentType: T}) => { 
  type PaymentMethod = T extends PaymentMethodTypes.CARD ? Card : DirectDebit;

  const method = (paymentMethod: PaymentMethod) => {
    console.info(paymentMethod.type)
    if (paymentType === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD) {
      console.info(paymentMethod.type === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD);
    }
  }
}
```

In short the `typeof` operator returns the union of all possible values, which means it will actually be evaluating

```js
type PaymentMethod = PaymentMethodTypes.CARD | PaymentMethodTypes.DirectDebit extends PaymentMethodTypes.CARD ? Card : DirectDebit;
```

Which always fails, hence it defaults to `DirectDebit`

EDIT: From comments discussion, The TS engine isn't able to infer type discrimination across function boundaries, instead you should seek to purify your function, [see on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgTwqALgWWCgFgewCYAqCADsAM5QDeAUFFAMICCASgCJQC8UARAMZwAnPNwA0tKKwCSzAKL0CAfVYyAQpIKceeAJYDgvFArzAARtpSjqAX2rUUJYA0F5NNOvdIAuWImQh0mLiEDmQAdExs1rYejqy6+iispuau4jHe8EioGNj4RKRhUrLySqrqUdS8OCBkKAw4EMTVqABi2gAemgA8GsDtKKB4FJl+AbnBBQB8ABSUUMS+qPmOVt6UC1n+y94EVgCUnJNUUGkOPptjQZq9-YPDi-45QcthEewA-E5CUN5xegZJMwoADc4gA9GC6AA9d62OhVGp1ZDjTTTDajJ74DIPS74A4cI5uOhQBFkHAAG2AoW0IAAZjg0TjMXhQjE9uI6NpaVBGRdmayzhwhecMYE8iFwixWAcicSSdUyZTqXSGejsmKWTFOMKRurxi9JWw9qC5VYoMByWRHLLiaSKVSafTeaLxgLSNquLrHhqDW9jVAIVAukKQ6Gw6GoAQsNoKGRcGByS5aXBtOSOVAbHQbFYgA)

```js
const ComponentFix = <T extends PaymentMethodTypes>({ paymentType }: {paymentType: T}) => { 
  type PaymentMethod = T extends PaymentMethodTypes.CARD ? Card : DirectDebit;

  const method = (paymentMethod: PaymentMethod) => {
    console.info(paymentMethod.type)
    if (paymentMethod.type === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD) {
      console.info(paymentMethod.type === PaymentMethodTypes.CARD);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't narrow the type correctly either I'm afraid, check out the very bottom of [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/m350jw). I experimented with that too. I feel like there's something really simple here all three of us are missing. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is because the inner function isn't pure, so TS fails to discriminate. I'll add an edit for the fixed version.

Comment: I had the impression they were doing the branching on `paymentType` rather than `paymentMethod.type` for a reason (whether it's a good reason I don't know). With the edit, the parameter is no longer used at all at runtime (though we don't know what else the function was doing that's omitted).